# How can I remove hidden windows of Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox

Firefox sometimes pops open windows even though the settings prohibit it.  Most of these appear to go off-screen.

I can tell,

- Because a tiny few fail to go off-screen
- Some of them show a white window before moving off.
- The number of tasks in Task Manager for Firefox keeps increasing (uncorrelated with the number of tabs open).

Is there a way to close down just these windows/processes.

I have now determined these are popups from `NoScript`.  Sometimes they stay on the screen and I can close them.  Other times, a faint outline is shown and then it disappears.  I think it goes off-screen.  When I get a few of these, Firefox seems to slow down appreciably. (I disabled `NoScript` globally, a few days ago to determine if this was the culprit.  But it still pops up these windows complaining about CORS.)

I know that I can close them from the taskbar, but not knowing which process belongs to which window/tab, means I have to close all of them.  Which I do a few times a day.

Comment: 1. what FFox version, and what extensions? 2. That should not be happening. Perhaps some sites are white-listed; is so, remove them. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pop-blocker-settings-exceptions-troubleshooting .

Comment: which version of windows? I hover over the firefox icon in the taskbar and get a nice preview of every window/tab open in firefox, and can close it from there

Comment: The number of Firefox processes does not correspond to the number of tabs. No modern browser works that way any longer. You may have uncaught Windows, but the number of processes is Not evidence of this.

Comment: Yea, this needs more info as to what kind of processes these are. You can check details with e.g. Process Explorer.